# how do I add gdscript to gitattributes

Tags: godot, gitattributes

I see that I can do: 
https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes/blob/master/Unity.gitattributes

```
# Unity
*.cginc              text
*.cs                 text diff=csharp
*.shader             text
```

but can I do

```
*.gd                text diff=gdscript
```

I tried:
 googling diff=gdscript but nothing came up. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/k3tk52/godot_and_git_part_8_git_lfs_and_dealing_with/

Answer (score 2):

There are many [built-in diff patterns](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/userdiff.c#L38) but "gdscript" isn't one. *And no, don't use "python".*

---

This is how my .gitattributes for Godot currently looks like:

```
*.gd text eol=lf
*.godot text eol=lf
*.tres text eol=lf
*.tscn text eol=lf
*.cfg text eol=lf
*.import text eol=lf
* text=auto
```

*I use Windows. And yes, those are the line endings for Godot. It will save you trouble.*